# Ansible jinj2 template whitespace issue between two lines

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Ansible jinja2 template is creating whitespace when converting to yaml. This is causing conflict for application startup.

Playbook main.yml

```
- name: Parse a cm yaml file
  template:
    src: "cm.yaml.j2"
    dest: "cm.yaml"
```

If we look at after yaml conversion -  both caData & redirectURI is appearing on same line. Please suggest a way to have these lines seperated during j2 to yaml conversion.

```
caData: |
       SS0tLS1CRUdJTiEDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUMSRENDQWRpZ0F3SUJBZ0lRSktsYVVsa0RQDFZQSkQvbTQrd2FwVEFSQmdrcWhraUc5dzBCQWFzRkFEQTBNVEl3TUFZRFZRUUQKRXlsTmFXTnlddddddd==        redirectURI: https://argocd-sbx.com/api/dex/callback
```

before yaml conversion:
cm.yaml.j2

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  dex.config: |
      config:
        caData: |
          {% if platform_name == 'gitops' and network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% elif network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}{{ vars[ network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% elif platform_name == 'gitops' %}{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% else %}{{ vars[ env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% endif %}
        redirectURI: {% if platform_name == 'gitops' and network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}https://{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% elif network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}https://{{ vars[ network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% elif platform_name == 'gitops' %}https://{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% else %}https://{{ vars[ env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% endif %}/api/dex/callback
        usernameAttr: email
```

After yaml conversion -
cm.yaml

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  dex.config: |
      config:
        caData: |
          SS0tLS1CRUdJTiEDRVJUSUZJQ0F...        redirectURI: https://ingress1.example.com/api/dex/callback
        usernameAttr: email
```

Tried following - https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.9.x/templates/#whitespace-control by adding "-" on the cadata if statement however not helping

Comment: It would be helpful if you could trim the information in your question to only that which is required to reproduce your problem. If the problem is only with the `caData` and `redirectUri` lines, we really don't need to see everything else.

Comment: (I've made this change for you this time.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to introduce an explicit newline in your template. If I have template `cm.yaml.j2` that looks like this:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  dex.config: |
      config:
        caData: |
          {% if platform_name == 'gitops' and network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% elif network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}{{ vars[ network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% elif platform_name == 'gitops' %}{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% else %}{{ vars[ env + '_' + dc + '_sso_caData' ] }}{% endif %}

        redirectURI: {% if platform_name == 'gitops' and network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}https://{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% elif network_zone is defined and network_zone != '' %}https://{{ vars[ network_zone + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% elif platform_name == 'gitops' %}https://{{ vars[ platform_name + '_' + env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% else %}https://{{ vars[ env + '_' + dc + '_ingress_host' ] }}{% endif %}/api/dex/callback
        usernameAttr: email
```

Then this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    platform_name: gitops
    network_zone: bar
    env: devel
    dc: dc1
    gitops_bar_devel_dc1_sso_caData: |-
       SS0tLS1CRUdJTiEDRVJUSUZJQ0F...
    gitops_bar_devel_dc1_ingress_host: ingress1.example.com
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: cm.yaml.j2
        dest: cm.yaml
```

Produces:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  dex.config: |
      config:
        caData: |
          SS0tLS1CRUdJTiEDRVJUSUZJQ0F...
        redirectURI: https://ingress1.example.com/api/dex/callback
        usernameAttr: email
```

Which is I think exactly what you want.

---

I think it's worth considering whether or not templates are the right solution in this situation. Because you're generating structured (YAML) output, you might be better off creating in-memory data structures and then dumping them to YAML using the `to_nice_yaml` filter. This might reduce some complexity around handling multiline values, and it certainly removes any Jinja-related line ending shenanigans.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. after giving explict line , getting /n on few areas in yaml when i do - "kubectl get cm argocd-cm -n argocd -o yaml " getting below

    \   caData: |\n      SS0tLS1CRUdJTiEDRVJUSUZJQ0F...
    \       \n    redirectURI: https://ingress1.example.com/api/dex/callback
    \   usernameAttr: email\n    emailAttr: email\n    groupsAttr: Group"